# поиск по категориям яндекс карты

Tags: yandex-places-api

Подскажите, Существует ли поиск по категориям, например «Парк». Т.е. если я ищу все парки в определенной области, мне не попался обувной магазин с названием «Парк обуви».
На моем примере видно, при поиске «парк культуры и отдыха, Астана» находит
-парк Чемоданов
-Слобода, офис

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Как такового параметра для поиска по категории нет, но можно отфильтровать уже полученные ответы по проперти `["CompanyMetaData"]["Categories"][0]["class"]`

Список рубрик на русском языке: https://yandex.ru/support/nmaps/app_poi.html